# Sefardic contemporaries for Techelet?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, techeles, jewish-books

Are there any Sefardic Poskim today that have written a book and discuss the Techelet? If so, can you bring one that is FOR the Techelet?

Comment: Are you looking for a book by a Sephardi author or a book about techelet written in the Sephardi tradition of psak?

Comment: I am looking for any Sefardic contemporary that endorses the Techelet they have nowadays.

Comment: I assume you mean murex trunculus, not cuttlefish.

Comment: @sq33g yes.....

Comment: @sq33G and it's called Sepia Officialnalis

Comment: btw, if someone has the time, I suggest going through the long list of rabbis found on this page http://www.tekhelet.com/pub.htm  click on the halacha tab, and see if any of those rabbis there are Sephardic

Comment: @avi does that list say the Rav Asher Weiss Shlit"a wears Techelet?

Comment: @avi That list is not a list of rabbis who wear or endorse P'til Tekhelet. It is a list of rabbis who have written on the subject within the past half century or so, with a link to what they wrote.

Comment: @SethJ http://www.tekhelet.com/Kuntreis5771/p7-17.pdf what does this have to do with Techelet?

Comment: @HachamGabriel No the list just gives a link to what he wrote on the topic.  He gives a very in depth review of wearing a talit and the mitzvah of Tzizit.

Comment: @avi not really Techelet though...

Comment: I don't have hebrew on this current keyboard, did you search for the word?

Comment: @HachamGabriel I'm not sure why you are addressing me...?

Comment: @SethJ sorry...

Comment: BTW in the Jewish Press this week there is an article about the last 20 years of Techelet, I have not read it yet, but I noticed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HaRav HaGaon Meir Mazuz Shelit"a (Mekor Ne'ema sim. 35). He writes that it "kedai-worthwhile" but not "mehuyav-obligatory" therefor he only wears it on Shabbat.

Comment: Why _Shabas_ as opposed to, say, Tuesday?

Comment: @msh210 I'm not really sure.

Comment: @msh210 I think it is because you are supposed to wear your nice clothes on Shabbes (when I asked Rav Herscehl Schechtar Shalit"a in person he told he may this citing a Gemara in Shabbes).

Comment: @msh210 see my answer; R. Mazuz himself explains why.

Comment: R' Mazuz wrote a while back in his *Bayit Ne'eman* that he "upgraded" to wearing _tekhelet_ everyday.

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi Yitzchok Yosef](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhak_Yosef) states (resp. Rishon LeZion OC §1) that after some have concluded upon thorough examinations that we have today authentic *techeles*, if one wants to wear them [concealed] then there is an element of *hiddur*.

[Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Eliyahu) (written source cited [here](http://www.harav.org/haravseliyahu.org/List.asp?PageID=580) by his son R. Shmuel Eliyahu) did not personally wear *techeles* but held it was permitted to wear.

[Rabbi Shalom Messas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalom_Messas) writes in a resp. dated from 2003 (Shemesh U'magen vol. 4 OC §24:3) that since the majority of rabbis do not wear *techeles* "since it is not extant" therefore it is better to refrain from putting on something that is certainly not *techeles*.

[Rabbi Meir Mazuz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Mazuz) discussed *techeles* in numerous lectures (transcribed in 'Bayit Neeman') and a couple of times answered questions regarding it in the pamphlet 'Peninei HaParsha'. He has said that on Shabbos he wears *techeles* on his *talit gadol* (and explains his practice that he does so because 1) it's fairly "new" and should be slowly broken into, and 2) if he wore every day it'd look as if he's speaking against earlier authorities who didn't wear at all). In another response (printed in the PH) to an inquiry if it's recommended to wear *techeles*, he replies that even though we aren't certain about its authenticity at least we know (today) 80% that it is and so when in doubt of a biblical commandment we are stringent.

Comment: Interesting to compare R. Messas's view to his uncle's: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22015&st=&pgnum=208

Comment: Can you post the resp. Rishon LeZion OC 1?

Answer (score 2):

Moreinu Rav Eliyahu Ben-Haim (Rosh Av Beth Din Queens and Rosh Yeshiva at YU) strongly holds of the Techeles, and he himself wears on his Tallit Kattan and Gadol.

On [YUTorah](https://www.yutorah.org/rabbi-eliyahu-ben-chaim/) you can hear many of his comments in regard to the wearing of the Techeles.

Comment: Can you link to a particularly relevant recording of his there?

Comment: I added a link to the rabbi's list of lectures on YUTorah. If you have a better link (e.g. to a specific lecture where he talks about this) feel free to further edit.

Answer (score -2):

I could not find a source that tells you that a particular Rabbi says that Sephardim can wear Techelet, however there a plethora of websites which teach tying Tzitzit, both with and without Techelet, for both Ashkinaz and Sephard people. 
This seems to indicate that there is some sort of minhag which says Ashkanazim wear Tzitzit with and without Techelet and Sephardim wear Tzitzit with and without Techelet.
Sorry I couldn't find you the actual source.

Comment: The Rambam and the Raavad provided instructions on how to configure and tie tzitzit including techelet. The Sephardi-oriented instructions are presumably based on these.

Comment: No, @IsaacMoses I'm not how to tie them, I am asking if there are any Sefardic rabbis (poskim that wrote books) today that endorse the Techelet.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, I realize that. I'm providing some explanation about why Sephardi-oriented instructions for how to tie exist.

Comment: @IsaacMoses yeah but I would think we would follow the Shulhan Aruch.

Comment: @HachamGabriel No one follows the shulchan arukh. People think they tie according to it, but they don't.