# List of Techelet Wearers

Tags: rabbis, tzitzis, techeles

I was looking online for a list of people famous for deciding or influencing halacha, who currently wear Ptil Techelet Techelet ("Murex")
However I could not find one.

Does such a list exist?  If not, could someone provide a list here?

Update:

It seems that this page here "might" have a list of "famous" people who wear techelet, but I can't tell exactly. Certainly some of the rabbis in the halacha section say that you don't have to wear techelet, and they themselves don't. [tekhelet.com/pub.htm](http://www.tekhelet.com/pub.htm) However, there is too much nuance there for me to get a list from it, easily.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion for criteria of "famous" let me know.  It's not subjective, just hard for me to define.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/sefardic-contemporaries-for-techelet

Comment: Well, if you count me...

Comment: @avi are you looking for an official list?

Comment: @HachamGabriel I don't know what would be official about it.  But a  collection of "I saw Rav X wearing techelet at this and this wedding" would be just fine. or "Rav Y is known to wear techelet" also works.

Comment: I voted to close, based on this: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/

Comment: Maharsham apparently http://rabbikaganoff.com/can-we-identify-the-techeiles/ wore Radziner Tekhelet. This was before the Murex days so it doesn't answer this question, but it's a pretty big name of someone who rejected all the "we can't discover Tekhelet" stuff.

Comment: @SethJ how many strings? I think it would nice if we could include in the list below which shita each of these rabbonim follow in regards to the number of strings. And then as well (other perhaps less importantly) the way they tie them (which shita.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An incomplete list:

- [R' Meir Mazuz](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%96%D7%95%D7%96) (on Shabbat) - [source](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask?category=1097)
- [R' Herschel Schachter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter)
- [R' Yisroel Belsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Belsky) (when wearing a long frock coat to cover it)
- [R' Abraham Twerski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_J._Twerski) ([source](http://www.forward.com/articles/8276/))
- [R' Zalman Nechemia Goldberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zalman_Nechemia_Goldberg)
- [R' Simcha Kook](http://www.rehovotisrael.com/kook.html)
- [R' David bar Hayim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bar-Hayim)
- R' Yehoshua Buch
- R' Yoel Bin-Nun ([only on his suit-jacket](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11769/759))
- [R' Moshe David Tendler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_David_Tendler) ([source](http://www.forward.com/articles/8276/))
- [R' Tzvi Hersh Weinreb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzvi_Hersh_Weinreb) ([source](http://www.forward.com/articles/8276/))
- [R' Shlomo Dichovsky](http://www.vosizneias.com/77494/2011/03/01/israel-rabbi-dichovsky-appointed-director-of-rabbinic-courts/) ([source](http://www.forward.com/articles/8276/))
- [R' Mordechai Machlis](http://www.machlispresents.org/) ([You can see him at his minyan on shabbat morning wearing a tallit](http://www.machlispresents.org/))
- R' Kalman Epstein (heard from a talmid)
- [R' Dov Lior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dov_Lior) ([source](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%90_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA#.D7.94.D7.A8.D7.91_.D7.93.D7.91_.D7.9C.D7.99.D7.90.D7.95.D7.A8))
- R' Mosheh Lichtenstein (personal experience)
- R' Alan Kimche
- R' Shlomo Riskin (personal experience)
- R' Yitzchak Meir Morgenstern (adding from a comment)
- R' Yaakov Medan (personal experience)
- Yehuda Reisler
- R' Mois Navon
- Baruch Sterman, Ph.D
- Rav Eliyahu Tavger
- R' Moshe Taragin
- R' Doniel Schreiber (only on his tallit)
- R' Reuven Taragin
- R' Elyah Ber Wachtfogel (heard from a talmid)
- [R' Moshe Tzuriel](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C) (heard directly from the Rav himself)
- R' Menashe Yisroel Reisman (only on his tallis katan and only at home.)
- [R' Chaim Richman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Richman) of the Temple Institute (personal experience)

Anyone feel free to add.

Comment: Rabbi Yisroel Belsky only Shabbos

Comment: I remember being told that Rav Dichovsky wears techelet on a separate tallit that he puts on only in private. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: Can anyone verify that Hakham Ben-Haim, rosh yeshivah at RIETS and student of HaRav Ben Zion Abba Shaul, wears tekhelet?  I was at Rabbi Ben-Haim's minyan on Yom Kippur 5772 and I recall that his tzitzit had some blue threads.

Comment: i have heard from a talmid that Rav Kalman Epstein of Shaar haTorah wears techeles

Comment: @HachamGabriel Did you ever find out which shita Rav Yitzchak Meir Morgenshtern goes like in regards to the number of strings?

Comment: I am a talmid of Rav Elya ber he sure does, but his talis in Yeshiva is regular.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%90%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F

Comment: https://thelehrhaus.com/commentary/rav-nachum-rabinovitch-and-the-art-of-ancient-dyeing/

Comment: See https://bluefringes.com/notable-wearers/ for more wearers, most with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

R' Shlomo Riskin - I saw it with my own eyes, and when someone asked about them, his exact comment was:

> You have an opportunity for a mitzvah d'orayta - how can you not wear them ?

Later he mentioned that they were from P'til Techelet.

Comment: I saw Rav Berl Wein with techelet (tied Rambam) on his tallis gadol. I didn't notice whether he had it on his tallis katan.