# What is the downside to wearing techeiles?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, techeles

There are many [Compelling arguments to support Techelet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12592), although it's not yet [universally accepted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7554).

A friend of mine bought P'til Tekhelet *Murex* techeiles, and went to his rabbi (who I know and respect) to ask for advice on how to tie it, and his rabbi told him "Don't."

While I'm pursuing the answer to the question through other means, what possible reasons are there to say ***not*** to wear *techeiles*? Let's say that *Murex* is not the *chilazon*, and we have some strings that have been dyed blue for no reason. What problem could there be in attaching those strings to my *tzitzis*?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8711/732

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What would happen if you put on Techelet in Galut according to that idea? Would your Mitzva of Tzitzit be lessened?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/why-is-techeles-not-universally-accepted/8711#comment21912_8913

Comment: See the new Torat Chacham Baruch Chelek Aleph who discusses this issue.

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/hamaayan/thelet-2.htm

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=55555&st=&pgnum=114

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ybnw_DCq98&t=5666s "I don't know."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You ask, "let's say that Murex is not the chilazon, and we have some strings that have been dyed blue for *no reason*. What's the problem with that?" (*my emphasis*)

If there really is **no** reason to dye them blue whatsoever, then doing so would be a violation of the Shulchan Aruch (9:5), who says that careful people use strings of the same color as the garment, and we use a white garment, and the Rama there who notes that the custom is to use white (this is pointed out by R. Elyashiv in his collected teshuvos, 1:2). While the Chazon Ish (3:25) and the Radziner Rebbe ([Ein HaTecheiles 1:40:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34404&st=&pgnum=166)) don't think that this applies to all of the strings, many poskim seem to assume that all four strings should be white, in the absence of techeiles.

This stringency, however, would not be enough of a reason to say not to use techeiles if there's any reason at all to assume that it might be correct.

Let's assume, then, that it's a matter of doubt, and (the assumption is) that one should be stringent as ספק דאורייתא לחומרא. Why not dye them with the new blue?

1. A halachik reason: Many (including R. Moshe Shternbach, Teshuvos V'Hanhagos 1:26 and 4:5) have written that placing something extra on tzitzis with the intent to possibly perform a mitzvah, even out of doubt, is violating the prohibition of bal tosif. (This is the indication of the Gemara in Zevachim 81a, and though the Ritva Sukkah 31b says otherwise, there were many poskim throughout history on both sides of this question).
2. A kabbalistic reason: There are apparently kabbalistic reasons to avoid using real techeiles strings nowadays anyway, which was the objection of R. [Yisrael Yehoshua Trunk](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0020_0_20068.html) (Shu"t Yeshuos Malko O.C. 1-3). (It's hard for this to be understood literally as Kabbalah can't uproot a biblical obligation. Rav Asher Weiss suggests the intention might be more along the lines of: kabbalah tells us that the true techeiles has been lost and so anyone who thinks they are wearing it nowadays must be donning a spiritually destructive fake.)
3. A meta-halachik reason: I've been told by a posek that he was worried that if we come to dye them blue from the murex out of doubt, then future generations might mistakenly believe that there's a tradition that this is the proper chilazon. This is problematic because (1) it is a 'ziyuf hatorah', a misrepresentation of the Torah, which the Maharshal (Yam Shel Shelomo B.K. 4:9) thinks is so terrible as to be worth dying for (2) if Eliyahu does come and provides us with a different snail, things could get very awkward and we might not know what to do.

If you are going to wear it in public, then we can add that R. Shternbach (ibid.) prohibits wearing blue tzitzis in public because of the prohbition of 'lo tisgodedu', of making apparent divisions in halakhic practice among different people.

Of course, the assumption above that there is a formal halachik doubt here is debatable as well. R. Shternbach (ibid.) writes that something without a tradition cannot even be considered a safek. Also, R. Soloveitchik (Shiurim L'Zecher Abba Mori, pg 228) as well as several others quote the Beis Halevi (though [there is some debate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8363/) if he actually said this) as saying that something that has been lost to tradition is equivalent to a tradition that something has been lost; meaning, it's as if there's a mesorah *not to use anything as blue* until Eliyahu or the like can reinstate it from their own mesorah, not just from arguments.

Additionally, it isn't at all true that the evidence is 'compelling' to everyone that the murex trunculus is the correct fish for dying techeiles. There are good answers to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/why-is-techeles-not-universally-accepted/8363), both in terms of archaeological evidence and halakhic literature regarding the identity of the *chilazon.* Rav Asher Weiss and [Rav Shlomo Miller](http://kollel.com/sites/default/files/rav_miller_shiurim/RSM-Techeilis-all.pdf), both widely accepted poskim, do not think that there is enough evidence to even raise a doubt, and discourage the use of techeiles (without really providing an answer to this question). For many people, the fact that these poskim are unconvinced is enough of a reason not to view it as a doubt. (The list of poskim that have discouraged it extends far beyond these, though of course it isn't unanimous, and those who do wear techeiles have answers to the above issues. You asked about the potential downsides).

Comment: +1 Re 3: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13173/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13153/759

Comment: I wonder if having stripes on the Tallis (as many ashkenazim do) would be enough to allow for multicolored strings (accd to the rambam). I suspect it would only help if the stripes reached all the way to the corner itself (something I've never seen done, but probably could be arranged without too much complaining from the manufacturers or the 'gedolim').

Comment: @DoubleAA I've asked a Rav before about the stripes, and he said that it only matters which single color is of the majority of the beged. But he didn't have a source and i haven't looked into it

Comment: @DoubleAA also re #3: apparently [R. Seriah Deblitzky](http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=766&start=40#p19693) feels the same way. (Note that he quotes Wikipedia which in turn quotes that very forum... almost an example of [this](https://xkcd.com/978/) but not quite)

Comment: @Matt Original sources: Wikipedia editors Rabbi [Ro'i Zak](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93:%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%99_%D7%96%D7%A7) of Itamar (I think) and [Chanan Fisher](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93:%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9F_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8).

Comment: Matt please look through my edits and feel free to edit further.

Comment: (You may be interested in Maharil (5:2) וסברא הוא דשמא יחזור דבר לקילקולו שיהא תכלת מצוי, כ"ש למאי דכתב סמ"ג דאותו דג חלזון הוא בים המלח וכתב סימנין, בקל היה לעשות תכלת seems no Mesorah is needed (or that Mesorah from written texts is sufficient).)

Comment: Link to Rav Shlomo Miller doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding #1, Rav Shternbuch says if a person puts in tzitzis with a stipulation, it's fine. His only problem is putting it on without any stipulation, in the hopes that it's techeiles.

Comment: There is a clip of Rav Asher Weiss saying that you lose absolutely nothing by wearing murex trunculus, he just doesn't think you gain anything either. You can find it on youtube

Comment: @Eliyahu https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyBRw0vp564

Comment: Rumors are going around the R Sternbuch has started wearing techelet in private, cc @robev

Comment: @DoubleAA yes I know someone who told me this from R. Sternbuch's grandson. They said he was chozer from his teshuvos and wears it betzinah...not sure

Answer (score 3):

Rav Moshe Heinemann says that there is a problem of the curse brought in the Gemara [Baba Metzia 61b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.61b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he):

> אמר רבא למה לי דכתב רחמנא יציאת מצרים ברבית יציאת מצרים גבי ציצית יציאת מצרים במשקלות אמר הקב"ה אני הוא שהבחנתי במצרים בין טפה של בכור לטפה שאינה של בכור אני הוא שעתיד ליפרע ממי שתולה מעותיו בנכרי ומלוה אותם לישראל ברבית וממי שטומן משקלותיו במלח וממי שתולה קלא אילן בבגדו ואומר תכלת הוא
>
> Rava says: Why do I need the mention of the exodus from Egypt that the Merciful One wrote in the context of the halakhot of the prohibition against interest (see Leviticus 25:37–38), and the mention of the exodus from Egypt with regard to the mitzva to wear ritual fringes (see Numbers 15:39–41), and the mention of the exodus from Egypt in the context of the prohibition concerning weights (see Leviticus 19:35–36)? Rava explains: The Holy One, Blessed be He, said: I am He Who distinguished in Egypt between the drop of seed that became a firstborn and the drop of seed that did not become a firstborn, and I killed only the firstborn. I am also He Who is destined to exact punishment from one who attributes ownership of his money to a gentile and thereby lends it to a Jew with interest. Even if he is successful in deceiving the court, God knows the truth. And I am also He Who is destined to exact punishment from one who buries his weights in salt, as this changes their weight in a manner not visible to the eye. And I am also He Who is destined to exact punishment from one who hangs ritual fringes dyed with indigo [kala ilan] dye on his garment and says it is dyed with the sky-blue dye required in ritual fringes. The allusion to God’s ability to distinguish between two apparently like entities is why the exodus is mentioned in all of these contexts.

Even though the Gemara is clearly saying that this is on one who comes to trick people, Rav Heinemann applies the rule of קללת חכם אפילו על תנאי היא באה, the curse of a Sage, even if it is stated conditionally, it comes ([Makkos 11a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Makkot.11a.21?lang=bi)).

<del>Note that this problem is only if Murex indigo is included in the category of kala ilan. This is arguable. If we take kala ilan to be the name of the indigo plant and not the dye produced from it, we can say definitively that the Murex is not that plant. I think this is the reason no one else has brought up this issue.</del>

I had understood that only actual kala ilan was included in the curse, but in a question and answer session [here](http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/6521/) (1:07-1:09) Rav Heinemann says that even if it is not kala ilan, if it is not certainly techales, the curse applies. (He seems to apply this even to what in fact is techales if one doesn't know that with certainty. I don't know how he includes that in the curse, this not being kala ilan in any sense.)

Comment: More likely, the reason no one else said this is that by the same logic, even in the future with Mashiach-given vadai tekhelet the curse will still apply. If the whole point of his argument is literally 'stated limitations do not apply', then there is really no argument from any classical source and it's just him stating his opinion.

Comment: By the same logic too, lending one's money without interest is included in the curse there. So too honestly lending a non-Jew's money out with interest is included in the curse.

Comment: Rav Heinemann is not stupid, and how do you think he would respond to your quips? It says specifically "claims that his money is a non-Jew's and lends it with interest", it does not say explicitly "in order to trick people."

Comment: I don't think he's stupid! I suspect he'd respond that I'm right but for other reasons, perhaps political, he can't accept murex tekhelet so he's coming up with difficult speculation to justify that given conclusion talmudicly. Well, if we were in private and he thought I wouldn't repeat it over to others, that's what I think he'd say.

Comment: @DoubleAA you can listen to Rav Heinemann "explain" his view [here](http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/6521/). The comparison you're trying to make to lending isn't appropriate, because it's not the same act; you should compare it to lending _your own money out with interest_, which is indeed prohibited anyway even if you aren't trying to be deceitful. With tekhelet, the point is that the actual act of wearing/tying blue strings is subject to a curse

Comment: He says "if it is  tekheles, there is also a possibility that the klala will take effect because the chachmim said the ribbono shel olam is going to give a punishment to someone who puts kla ilan on his beged and says it's tekheles, so what happens if you say tekheles and it is tekheles? that's the case of al chinam.... it could be that a person actually gets a klala even if it is tekheles, maybe the mitzva of tekheles is when he [made?] it" @הנערהזה if I understand him correctly neither of you are representing him correctly. Seems preposterous though that evryone would have made it themselves

Comment: @DoubleAA you're right regarding what Rav Heinmemann actually said - he believes that even true tekheiles in included in the curse, but says (at 1:08:00 or so) "the mitzvah of techeiles is meigin [protects]" and it's the protective power of doing a mitzvah which one cannot rely on if he is unsure whether the mitzvah is truly being fulfilled. This is very foreign to my way of thinking, but I think that the idea (that the 'curse' is sufficient reason to avoid using techeiles of uncertain validity) is defensible in principle

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Heinemann's primary objection, according to what he says first in that recording, is that "none of the gedolim" believe that there is enough evidence to even raise a doubt, otherwise they would wear the blue themselves, and to imply that someone is 'smarter' than "the gedolim" constitutes a chilul Hashem

Comment: Actually, this is only a problem if you are dishonestly passing off the wrong dye as real tekheiles. And possibly it only applies to the salesperson who thereby is robbing his customers. Which is why he is lumped together with someone who lies to lend his money with interest or who cheats on their weights.

Comment: @הנערהזה this objection is not proven wrong as many more rabbis and gedolim from all the spectrum have started wearing Techelet including R Mazuz, R Machpuch, R Shachter, R Moshe Karp and R Hamekubal Dovid Kook and many other well respected  rabbanim

Answer (score 1):

To defend the second answer of MichoelR, that a layman should not wear techales when he sees that his Rabbanim do not, this is clearly spelled out in the [Mishna Brura (63:6)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.63.6?lang=bi):

> כתב ביש"ש פ"ז דב"ק סימן מ"א מי שמחמיר ... ואפילו אם אינו פשוט כ"כ להתיר לא יחמיר נגד דברי רבו אם לא שיש לו ראיה לסתור דבריו עכ"ל:
>
> Someone who is stringent ... even if it is not so clear to permit (or require) the act, one should not be stringent against the word of his Rabbi unless he has a proof to contradict his word.

(My adding the case of some positive act being required is based upon the context where the Mishna Brura brings this.)

This is not like the [case](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94587/19563) of where one's Rabbi does not wear tefilin, brought in the comments on that answer. (I kid you not; that is the case there.) There it should be clear to everyone that every person must wear tefilin. Here it is not clear to people that Murex dye is techales, so one who does not posses the proofs to that effect should not be stringent against the word of his Rabbi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Mishnah Berurah is talking about being stringent on a chumrah, and not fulfilling a mitzvah when no one else is...?

Comment: Indeed this answer mistakenly conflates two different "kinds" of "chumra": the kind where some people act strictly in defference to a position we don't rule like, and the kind where when there is a doubt about a biblical mitzva one must act stringently. The former kind is where Yuhara is relevant, not the latter kind. The question of whether or not to wear tekhelet, though, has nothing to do with the former kind.

Comment: I really would have been happy to only bring the second half of the quote, but didn't see a good way to do that. The first half, about a chumra, is patently irrelevant, as stated. But the second half is more relevant. And there yuhara is not part of the equation. One could still argue that in the absence of proof one must follow his Rabbi only on rabbinic requirements and not a biblical commandment, as the source for the [Yam shel Shlomo](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40932&st=&pgnum=152) is from muktzah, but that is a shakey argument.

Comment: Thanks! I see you got downvoted too! :) Welcome to the club.

Comment: How many gedolim have to wear tekheiles for this not to apply? We are certainly past a niut hanikar (a visible minority).

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13027/1570

Comment: @MichaBerger, the original source was because Abbaye went against Rabbah. Perhaps this would mean whenever going against a first-hand pasak, irrespective of anyone else's opinion. But I hear your suggestion that when there are two accepted opinions amongst the poskim that this does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Controversy aside as to what the techeiles dye really is, there is good reason not to reinstate it.
Rabbi Cohen writes in [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Techeiles):

> the Beis Halevi (R’ Yosef Ber Soloveitchik, 1820-1892) maintained that as the techeles has been lost from our mesorah, tradition, it should not be reinstated, irrespective of the evidence.

He continues by explaining that there is a precedent for this among other mitzvos, such as Birchas Koahanim.

Comment: What's the good reason?

Comment: Why can't he wear it without reinstating it?

Comment: Why doesn't that site cite how it knows what the Beis Halevi thought about that? (Hint: he never actually wrote that anywhere and in fact wrote the opposite. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8363/759)

Comment: I don't know. I believe the Briskers all believe that side of the story, though think the Radziner Rebbe wrote something else from the Brisker..

Comment: Just saw your comment - thanks for that link! Any idea where it is in his book?

Comment: Nope. You should see the edits to the question. Incidentally I have heard some Briskers claim the story you cite is made up because the techelet industry was being run by chasidim (who they didn't like much).

Comment: @DoubleAA still don't get it, sorry. Just because R. Elyashiv didn't like the version cited by Reb Chaim's grandchildren he didn't think that their version was authentic? Is that proof? but it's fine

Comment: @Matt That answer says there are two traditions about what he said. One is recorded in writing and endorsed by R Elyashiv and makes a good deal of sense. One is oral and is quite an extremely novel chiddush. None of that is hard proof, I agree.

Comment: The Maharil (Chadashot 5:2), though, said the opposite: that we could reinstate techeles at any time by looking for the signs of the right animal.

Comment: The Torah doesn't say "Wear techelet IF you have a mesora for it"

Comment: that was during the haskala movement. maybe he would say differently today?

Comment: This is a distinctly Brisker approach to halakhah. If you aren't so Brisker as to not use a community eruv - not even for the Mrs to push a baby carriage, or to not wear tzitzis on Shabbos, or... this isn't what you hold.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tshuva from Reb Elyashiv where he says either the tradition of what techeiles is was lost, or it wasn't lost and there was some reason the Rabbis allowed its disuse. He says we should not change as this would qualify as a minhag and al titosh toras imecha.

I have another idea that I've mentioned to some people that they've appreciated. Let's see what the Mi Yodeans think.

The gemara in Bava Metzia 61b reads like this. Rava said why did the Torah mention Yetzias Mitzraim by Ribis by tzitzis and by weights? Hashem said I am the one who recognized in Egypt between the drop who was of a bechor and the drop that was not of a bechor. I am He who will get back at someone who uses a nonjew as a pretext and lends his money to a Jew with ribbis, and from someone who keeps his weights in salt, and someone who hangs Kala Ilan, fake techeiles, on his clothing.

The idea of the first two is that this person is gaining monetarily from his deceit. The case of hanging fake techeiles also can be explained this way, as the Rosh in fact did see there #4 'one who hangs Kala Ilan on his clothing to sell in place of Techeiles'.

However Tosafos seems to understand differently. Tosafos points out 'even though this is a transgression his mitzvah of tzitzis, even still the passuk is needed so that he will be transgressing from when he hangs those strings.' Tosafos is dealing with the actual fulfillment of the mitzvah, not the issue of stealing. The fact that within the parameters of the mitzvah a person will transgress simply by putting fake techeiles on his clothing, even before wearing them, is a good reason not to put techeiles on which might be fake.

One can claim that this passuk is only talking about someone who puts fake techeilas knowingly, which would then have no bearing on today's situation where it is put on out of doubt, but that would be an unprecedented novalle.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20372/discussion-on-answer-by-user6591-what-is-the-downside-to-wearing-techeiles).

Comment: As far as I know he has one responsum on this topic and he doesn't say what you say he says. Can you cite it?

Answer (score 0):

I heard a shiur from [Rav Kleinman](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/speaker?l=645) that he heard a rumor that Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky wore techeiles in secret. When he asked him about it, Rav Kamenetsky made a point of pulling out his tzitzis to show they were all white. Rav Kleinman asked why Rav Kamenetsky was so emphatic on the issue, and he answered that it is due to the Aruch HaShulchan, who rejected the Radziner's techeiles completely based on the writings of the students of the Arizal, that the identity of the chilazon is lost until Mashiach comes.

Another point brought up by Rav Elyashiv in his teshuva: Even if we identify the chilazon, it is a machlokes Rashi and Rambam how to prepare it, so we don't know what to do with it.

Another point I heard from a Rav is there is a concern that if people start wearing techeiles, people will try to use it to recreate the Bigdei Kehunah and do the avodah on the Temple Mount. A friend of mine who took a tour in Jerusalem was told by the guide that "Rav Hershel Shachter says this is techeiles, so we can do the avodah." Never mind that Rav Shachter says he only wears it misafeik.

Comment: Regarding the last point, the last paragraph of [Igrot Moshe O.C. 5:15](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=74) may be relevant.

Comment: I don't see how. If you are wrong about it being techeiles, then according to many opinions there is a chiyuv kares. That is much worse than Rav Moshe's case.

Comment: That's a different step in the analogy. R. Moshe says that you can be machmir in one case without worrying that it will lead to being meikil in the future. Transposed to techeiles (though, of course, the parallel is not exact) it would mean that you can be machmir by tzitzis without worrying that it will lead to being meikil by avodah.

Comment: Presumably this has to be judged on a  case-by-case basis. Especially when there already are people agitating for this dangerous idea.

Comment: If they're agitating for this dangerous idea, you probably won't be able to stop them. In any case, saying that someone should refrain from doing a mitzvah because someone else might do an aveirah seems like a stretch. What if non-kohanim were agitating to do the avodah and having kohanim do it properly might encourage them? Would we cancel the avodah altogether? Or, to take a less extreme example, what if encouraging men to wear tefillin will embolden women to do so as well (assuming you hold that women wearing tefillin is problematic)?

Comment: Making a gezeirah to cancel a mitzvah due to some concern is something that Chazal/Sanhedrin do (e.g. shofar/lulav on Shabbos). For an individual rabbi to make such a gezeirah in the 21st century seems like overreach.

Comment: It's not canceling the mitzvah; it is saying the benefits to being machmir on this safek are outweighed by the costs.

Comment: Your first two paragraphs are irrelevant to the question of the downside to wearing them. Your last paragraph needs a source. We don't make up our own gezeiros, especially to annul a mitzvah doraisa. Also Rav Schachter says it's close to 100% the correct techeiles, so not sure why you say it's a safek for him.

Comment: If we actually have the ability to do the avodah and don't do it, that's also a chiyuv kareis of not bringing the Pesach.

Comment: I didn't want to get political, but when people try to go to the Temple Mount, it leads to attacks on Jews.  It really is more than kareis, it is a safeik nefashos. And the chances that we could do the avodah correctly nowadays without making it passul are practically zero, since we don't have an active practical mesorah.

Comment: @N.T. the threat of attacks is a temporary side consideration, unrelated to the discussion at hand. (unless you're suggesting that when the threat subsides we should no longer prevent wearing tekhelet for fear of avoda even if mashiach still hasn't come yet?)

Comment: Can you explain the relevance of the first two paragraphs? If not I'll remove them as not answering the question.

Comment: The first paragraph shows how strongly a major posek feels about the issue. Perhaps he considers wearing murex as contradicting the Arizal. The second just shows that it is impossible to know how to do it, which strengthens the points made in earlier answers.

Comment: Those are points, but not points relevant to answering this question.

Comment: FYI, there are many videos from "Gedolim," including R. Shmuel Kamenetsky, here: https://www.techeiles.org/techeiles-video-its-not-all-black-and-white/ (R. Kamenetsky says that he doesn't believe there is enough evidence to believe that the murex is the techeiles-chilazon, but for someone who is convinced, they should use it)

Comment: @הנערהזה That doesn't necessarily contradict what he said here.

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking, Rashi says at the end of parshas Shelach that the reason the torah mentions yetzias mitzroyim in the parsha of tzitzis is because just like HKBH was mavchin bein tipah shel b'chor l'tipa sheino shel b'chor, so too He knows the difference between one who puts on real techeiles and one who takes dye from a tree and calls it techeiles.  It could that that is the risk in wearing sofek techeiles, because apparently there is an issue with wearing something that you are considering techeiles that may not really be true techeiles.

Comment: "apparently there is an issue" I see no evidence for that. It just says God won't be fooled into thinking you are wearing techeiles, not that he will be angry with your or punish you or that you are doing anything wrong. Moreover, as long as you also think it's a safek there's no way it would be a problem since you wouldn't even be trying to trick anyone.

Comment: Regarding your first point, I think the mashmaus from Rashi is that Hashem is not happy when one does it, because otherwise, what is the point of Rashi's comment?  That Hashem knows the difference between real techeiles and fake techeiles?  Of course He knows the difference.  The point Rashi seems to be making is that one shouldn't do this because it is not right.   Your second point is kind of what I was thinking.  It could be that, assuming Hashem is not happy about what this person is doing, it would only be a problem if he does it b'meizid, and he uses a dye that he knows is not techeiles

Comment: (continuing my point abouve)  But if he uses something that is a sofek (like today's techeiles) it would not fall under this issue

Comment: No, you can say even more that, even if he purposely uses fake Tekhelet with no intention of tricking anyone (because he likes the color or it's all he has or whatever), it's also ok. The key here isn't that it's a safek but that no one is trying to trick anyone

Comment: @DoubleAA I think DoubleAA is right about this; a clear part of the Midrash is the deception involved. _Nevertheless_, I've heard in the name of Rav Heinemann that he thinks it would apply anyhow, because of the principle of "a curse of a sage happens even if the condition is not fulfilled." I haven't asked him for an explanation, but that was interesting.

Comment: @MichoelR in a recent Headlines podcast he said that exact idea

Comment: @MichoelR by the same logic, even in the future with Mashiach-given vadai tekhelet the curse will still apply...

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think that's correct, though I think that's a cute idea. You still need to identify the person that curse applies to.

Comment: @Michoel why limit it to individual people? Why limit it to the mitzva of tzitzit? Why limit it at all if the whole jist of his argument is literally 'stated limitations do not apply'.

Answer (score -2):

Surely it is obvious that if we *knew for sure* that this was not the real techeiles, then it would be a very bad thing to use it. It would be like if you can't get an esrog, using a lemon instead. As the gemara in [Sukkah 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.31b?lang=bi) says about that case, "It's obvious you shouldn't do that! No, you might say, do it in order that the mitzvah of esrog not be forgotten. The mishnah comes to say, it will lead to more damage, as people will be pulled into using it instead of the correct species." And to me this case seems much more obvious. At least there everyone knows that a lemon is not an esrog; here the confusion is built in.
Since that is so, it just becomes a question of how good is the evidence for and against, which is something that individual poskim will see differently.

Comment: "Since that is so, it just becomes a question of how good is the evidence for and against" That's not true. As Matt wrote "This stringency, however, would not be enough of a reason to say not to use techeiles if there's any reason at all to assume that it might be correct." In other words, once you're evaluating the worth of the different bits of evidence, this becomes irrelevant. It's only relevant to people who think there is literally no evidence at all (apparently such people exist, to my disbelief)

Comment: @DoubleAA "This stringency" - Matt meant, we prefer to use white! That is nothing compared to the very serious problems that result from people having a tradition to use the wrong dye. Whole different league.

Comment: Severity is not the issue here. Chazal are not gozer on a safek lemon. You can repeat Matt's item 3 as a meta halachic reason, but that's not the formal argument from the Gemara you cite. You admit this is only relavent if "if we *knew for sure*"

Comment: 'You admit this is only relevant if "if we knew for sure"' No, I brought a case where the answer is easy. One can use that case to understand nearby cases, such as where we are *almost* sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124611/discussion-between-michoelr-and-double-aa).

Comment: Very well, then -1. I have no problem with the sourced part of your answer. The unsourced extension of yours though is outright silly. The chance that anyone would forget how tekhelet was lost and rediscovered is laughable, and the only way murex is wrong is if there is some dye source that magically disappeared and was secretly erased off all the relevant historical records. Sure it's theoretically possible since literal miracles are possible, but if Eliyahu comes and reveals it everyone will understand full well what happened and there wont be a problem. Your concerns are entirely misplaced

Comment: And anyway the gist of this is already written up better than this and actually sourced in Matt's answer so what's the point of the unnecessary low-quality duplication? If you came to present an opinion that exists, Matt already did that. If you came to make an argument on your own, I find that you failed to make a compelling one and [am downvoting you to show readers the value of the contents of this post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4341/759).

Comment: @DoubleAA As I said, I think the basis of your attitude is that you consider murex to be very likely to be right, as you've made clear. Whether you know it or not, that is framing your attitude toward the upside and the downside. And Matt's answer is well-sourced, but it's not "some posek", it's an explicit gemara and perfectly obvious anyhow. No one who thinks that murex is unlikely would suggest it; you wouldn't either. What Matt does is jump from "no chance" (where he gave the wrong answer as I said) to "safek", which is not the territory I was working.

Comment: You are just speculating. Enjoy.

Comment: Well, I'm kinda speculating about you, which probably I shouldn't. But I think my answer correctly describes the exact attitude I see around me in the my little corner of the haredi community, right or wrong. Which was more-or-less the question.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I readily admit I consider the chance of a non-miraculous non-murex source of tekhelet to be negligible. And yet I still upvoted and even helped copy-edit Matt's answer. Your gemara says we don't use fake substitutes for a missing mitzva object which is a great source. The extension of that that you have speculated, even if it is believed by many people in any corner of any Jewish community, is a bad argument to apply to this case. (But as they say "history of nonsense is scholarship" so if you find some notable rabbi who said it I certainly won't downvote it.)

Comment: Honestly, chas veshalom to say what you said. If there is any chance the etrog is kosher, Chazal would say to use it. They were only talking about using a known fake. To be mevatel a mitzva deorayta for some made up chashash is borderline heresy. May people see us trying to do a mitzva and learn to follow us to try your best to grab any chance of an actual mitzva! The fact that the chashash of נפיק חורבא doesn't apply anymore and kol shekein to something as widely publicized and documented as tekhelet is a side point.

Comment: @DoubleAA "If there is any chance the etrog is kosher, Chazal would say to use it." I don't know why this is true. Chazal take chashashos very seriously. They told all Israel not to use techeiles on pishtan, maybe not to make tzitzis for pishtan at all, because of a remote chashash, and that's an asei vaday. And you know that they did this frequently. We are not always privy to their judgment calls on when a chashash is enough for them to be willing to be mevatel an asei. If there is a chashash, some posek might feel it is big enough to outweigh the chance of doing the asei.

Comment: "If there is any chance the etrog is kosher, Chazal would say to use it." Interesting. I had never thought that. Do you have a similar case in mind, where the halacha chases after a remote possibility of doing an asei? The closest that I can think of is something like being machmir for a rejected shitah, Rabbeinu Tam's tefillin and the like.

Comment: "some posek might feel it is big enough to outweigh the chance of doing the asei" Unless that posek is chazal they have no right to be doing that. You are confusing formal rabbinic prohibitions with your own worries.

Comment: "Unless that posek is chazal they have no right to be doing that." Another interesting comment.

Answer (score -2):

Slightly different approach than the answer I gave above, speaking as a *layman* rather than a rabbi. A mini-survey convinces me that (a) every Rav I follow in Baltimore doesn't wear blue, (b) many of them are pretty convinced that it isn't techeiles, and (c) no one around me wears them either. Once a month maybe I see someone in shul with blue tzitzis.
Given that this is so, for me there is an obvious downside to wearing blue tzitzis: It is a dismissal of the clear custom of (at least my part of) the community. It would be much weird-er than, say, suddenly starting to wear a gartel, which would make me uncomfortable as well. Maybe similar to if I stopped wearing a black hat, but more so there also.
I note that I do sometimes see people wearing blue tzitzis, no one makes a fuss of any kind and AFAIK no one really thinks anything of it. Perfectly acceptable. But it would be a move away from minhag hamakom.
(Update: and as Alex pointed out with his link in the comment, there is the issue of yuhara if done in public.)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94569/keeping-your-own-communitys-dinim-vs-yuhara/94587#94587

Comment: I'm not really seeing the comparison to gartel. One's a custom one's a biblical mitzvah. I guess I second @Alex's comment.

Comment: Not sure if you misunderstood Alex's comment but the teshuva cited is quite emphatic that you fulfill the mitzvah even if no one else does.

Comment: All I meant to take from Alex's comment is that there is an issue there that I left out.

Comment: @robev That would be in the case (Rav Sherira Gaon's case) where there is a clear mitzvah and a minhag not to do it. Here the custom of Baltimore (seems to be) that its rabbonim do not feel that there is any clear mitzvah at all. Maybe Rabbeinu Tam's tefillin in a non-Chassidic community would be a better fit? Remember, the OP's question was, is there a downside even if you don't know? Not, is there a downside if you're sure Murex Blue = techeiles?

Comment: @Michoel I don't see any difference between safek and vadai as regards R Shreira and Yuhara. What is it? Unless you're sure it's just a chumra and not a safek (like by RT tefillin) then skipping the mitzva is straight Bal Tigra which, as R Shreira taught, isnt justified by "avoiding Yuhara"

Comment: @DoubleAA "I don't see any difference between safek and vadai..." Yeah, but you surely see the difference between either one and a case where one's rav says, I don't think that's required at all. That is the case we're talking about, at least for me in Baltimore. I think.

Comment: @Michoel of course, but that isn't the question asked here afaict. We're discussing reasons to not wear it if you have some even small reason to wear it. Obviously if you think it's just wrong there's nothing to talk about since the downside then is just you're doing something stupid.

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't know why not. "what *possible reasons* are there to say not to wear techeiles? Let's say that Murex is *not* the chilazon, and we have some strings that have been dyed blue for *no reason* [italics mine]. What problem could there be..."

Comment: @DoubleAA Note that *this* answer is coming from the point of view of an am haaretz such as myself, who doesn't know much about the issues, but knows that his rabbonim don't think it is sufficient reason to wear it. So the OP question applies and I think my answer applies.

Comment: Context. The question as you interpret it is inane. The question interpreted as "[if i have some reason to think to wear it, what do I have to lose if it turns out] that Murex is not the chilazon, and we have some strings that have been dyed blue for [as it turns out] no [meaningful] reason. What problem could there be." is interesting. No one came to Mi Yodeya to ask why not do something pointless.

Comment: As I'm interpreting it it's a perfectly reasonable question, and indeed applies to me here and now. "I heard some chashuv people think it's techeiles but my rabbonim don't."

Comment: @DoubleAA I think our two readings of the question are interesting, but: I don't know what the OP meant, but he is referring to someone's "his rabbi" who said not to wear them. And he asked for an explanation, why would he do that, what's the downside? I think it is very likely that "his rabbi" is closer to the Not Techeiles side than to yours. Hence my two answers (both of which were downvoted!)