# Who exactly doesn't hold of Murex techailes?

Tags: techeles

One often repeated argument against the acceptance of Murex techailes is that "the Gedolim" don't accept it. Certainly there are many Gedolim who considered the issue, at least superficially, and did not start using the Murex. Often one Gadol would rely on another, for example Rav Chaim Kannievski (as can be seen in his responses in Dass Note, "כל רבותי לא החזיקו מזה"). My question is, who are these Gedolim who do not to accept this for their own reasons, without falling back on the opinions of others, that lesser rabbonim then supported themselves upon?

Note that it isn't always obvious who is really relying on others. Most responses from Rav Chaim would indicate, from lack of evidence to the contrary, that this was his independent conclusion. It is only from his more detailed response that we see not like that. But as far as we know, whose rejection is his own?

Comment: ,dupe ..........

Comment: related: [Why is techeles not universally accepted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7554/11501)

Comment: Rav Shternbuch in many teshuvos. Although someone told me he was chozer...who knows.

Comment: I personally spoke to Rav Shternbach twelve years ago, between his second and third teshovos, and he told me explicitly that "if we had techailes we would wear it. The reason we don't is because the tzadikei hador have not been moreh."

Comment: I haven't asked him, but those who have say that Rav Moshe Heinemann shlit"a is convinced that Murex dye is not techeiles.

Comment: (It could be that the word "convinced" I used is too strong.)

Comment: See this comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52823/what-is-the-downside-to-wearing-techeiles?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment413474_125538

Answer (score 2):

Rav Elyashiv in Kovetz Teshuvos. Rav Asher Weiss in Shu"t Minchas Asher chelek 2 simanim 2-6.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Yisroel Reisman (a Rosh Yeshiva in Torah Vodaath) in [this video](https://youtu.be/ZxO7R9nkM2U).

Comment: I believe that Rav Reisman's opinion is his own, but I doubt (perhaps without justification) that many other rabbanim relay upon him for this.